# Flink submit task failed

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I am using Flink1.6.1 and Hadoop2.7.5. on first I start a flink

```
bin/yarn-session.sh -n 2 -jm 1024 -tm 1024 -d
```

then submit a task

```
./bin/flink run ./examples/batch/WordCount.jar -input hdfs://CS-201:9000/LICENSE -output hdfs://CS-201:9000/wordcount-result.txt
```

I got a error:

> [root@CS-201 flink-1.6.1]# ./bin/flink run
>   ./examples/batch/WordCount.jar -input hdfs://CS-201:9000/LICENSE
>   -output hdfs://CS-201:9000/wordcount-result.txt 2019-05-19 15:31:11,357 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli
>   - Found Yarn properties file under /tmp/.yarn-properties-root. 2019-05-19 15:31:11,357 INFO 
>   org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - Found
>   Yarn properties file under /tmp/.yarn-properties-root. 2019-05-19
>   15:31:11,737 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli
>   - YARN properties set default parallelism to 2 2019-05-19 15:31:11,737 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 -
>   YARN properties set default parallelism to 2 YARN properties set
>   default parallelism to 2 2019-05-19 15:31:11,777 INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy                         -
>   Connecting to ResourceManager at CS-201/192.168.1.201:8032 2019-05-19
>   15:31:11,887 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli
>   - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
>   2019-05-19 15:31:11,887 INFO 
>   org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - No
>   path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class
>   org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
>   2019-05-19 15:31:11,891 WARN 
>   org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           -
>   Neither the HADOOP_CONF_DIR nor the YARN_CONF_DIR environment variable
>   is set.The Flink YARN Client needs one of these to be set to properly
>   load the Hadoop configuration for accessing YARN. 2019-05-19
>   15:31:11,979 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor
>   - Found application JobManager host name 'cs-202' and port '52389' from supplied application id 'application_1558248666499_0003' Starting
>   execution of program
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------  The program finished with the following exception:
>
> org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not
>   retrieve the execution result. (JobID:
>   471f0c2d047aba74ea621c5bfe782cbf)     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:474)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:85)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:426)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:804)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:280)
>     at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1120)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1754)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1120)
>   Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException:
>   Failed to submit JobGraph.    at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$8(RestClusterClient.java:379)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$5(FutureUtils.java:213)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:561)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:929)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could
>   not complete the operation. Exception is not retryable.   at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:911)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:899)
>     ... 12 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could
>   not complete the operation. Exception is not retryable.   ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Job
>   submission failed.]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:911)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:953)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
>     ... 4 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Job
>   submission failed.]   at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.parseResponse(RestClient.java:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$3(RestClient.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
>     ... 5 more

why it happen? and How to fix that..